# Custom Control Library and specifying handlers

Tags: maui

I have a custom MAUI control library that I use across several projects. I've been turning it into a NuGet library to make reuse easier.

Within this library is a custom ContentPage (call it `ModalPage`) that has an accompanying custom handler (call it `ModalPageHandler`) that derives from PageHandler and performs some magic on iOS/MacCatalyst. In my apps, I register this using the standard builder call to ConfigureMauiHandlers in MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(ModalPage), typeof(ModalPageHandler));
});
```

Everything works as expected.

However within the context of a control library, there is no access to the MauiAppBuilder in the main app as it's already been built.

How do I configure my control library so that the ModalPageHandler is the default handler being used without the consumer registering it? It must be possible as MAUI controls do it...I just can't find documentation on that linkage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Currently, Must do a work-around**

Add to library an `Init(builder)` function that must be called from `MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()` **in every app that uses your library**:

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
  var builder = ...;
  ...
  MyLib.Init(builder);   // Every app must do this, or your handlers/DI-injected-services won't work correctly.
  ...
  builder.Build();
}
```

In the library:

```cs
public static void Init(MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
  builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(ModalPage), typeof(ModalPageHandler));
  });

builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyCustomComponent>();
}
```

That's less obtrusive than having to explicitly refer to the handlers themselves.

---

---

**BONUS - (failed) ATTEMPT - ALMOST POSSIBLE, JUST NEED ONE MISSING METHOD**

Attempt to add handler in page class static constructor.

In the library:

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    // ONE-TIME initialization.
    public static MyPage()
    {
        IMauiHandlersFactory handlersFactory = Application.Current.Handler?.MauiContext?.Handlers;
        if (handlersFactory != null) {
            // Compile error: No such method.
            // TODO: No method exists to add handlers. They can only be added by MauiAppBuilder.
            handlersFactory.AddHandler(typeof(ModalPage), typeof(ModalPageHandler));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Interfaces available after MauiAppBuilder.Build() runs, only have getters; I don't see any way to add another handler.

TODO: I didn't investigate, to find out whether the runtime object (of handlersFactory) is a class that has such a method. If so, a (not guaranteed to work in future) work-around is to cast factory to that class. Then propose that the method be made available on the interface.

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing this with my dependency injection. I think I'm mostly hoping to find out how, for instance, a ContentPage or a Label gets assigned their individual handlers. I would think there would be some way of registering that linkage internally. Or at least I'd hope. Since this is in a NuGet package, I'd rather devs using it not need to add my handler to their MauiProgram.cs file.

Comment: Its quite common with Xamarin.Forms, and now Maui, for library packages to need an `Init` function, manually called at the correct point in startup. Without that, there is no way to get the library initialization to happen at the correct time. Consider how classes work, where static initialization is not done until some code runs that refers to the class. Unfortunately such a "lazy" approach won't work with the built-in .Net ServiceProvider; it is not permitted to add services after the `builder.Build();` line executes; an exception will be thrown if you attempt it. Must make some call.

Comment: See new section at start of answer. I've narrowed it down to a single place where it would be theoretically possible to add another handler, if that was added to IMauiHandlersFactory interface. I don't know whether there are any internal reasons to disallow this. You could add a "proposal" at `github maui issues`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Hopefully someone over at the MAUI team will enlighten us if there is a better way to deal with this going forward. I'll stick with your original approach for now. Thanks for your research!