# Maui Handlers using partial classes do always replace existing handlers? How to customize and existing control with Handlers?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I don't really understand Maui handlers using Partial class method. When using other method you have options like `AppendToMapping` that you can extend the current mapping but when I use partial classes, I get a new instance of the control always. I am not able to append the existing control. That means if i define a control that inherits from Maui control with some default values and registering this control with platforms specific handlers, my control loses predefined cross platform values. This is not the way Renderers are working xamarin.forms?
So what is this case and how to fix this?

Please dont suggest me to use  `Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping` because this does not exist in maui class library if i want to work with nuget packages.

Even Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) doesn't mention about partial classes to customize a control but mentions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create) Create a control. (yes there is something at the end with Partial class but this is totally irrelevant, not sure what is this about and MS documented something like that) Why? If that is not possible, thats a huge downgrade in Maui from Xamarin.forms.

**UPDATE:**

I have created a test repo with demo maui project and maui class library.

https://github.com/EmilAlipiev/TestMauiHandlers

under the class library you find the Old renderers under each platform and new upgraded Handlers under handlers folders.

1. So first run the Demo project in IOS without handlers. you can see the default value for text "this is default text" on the ui.
2. enable ConfigureMauiHandler in MauiProgram.cs in HandlersDemoApp
3. You see that default text is empty

Reason for that is Handlers are creating a complete new Entry instead of extending the Entry defined in the shared part i believe.

If i use renderers they will be just extended with the default cross platform definitions.

last question; I have this CustomEntry in the Class library because i want to created a nuget package. How do i register handlers within the class library?

Comment: 1) In that doc, there are multiple code snippets using `partial class`, which one(s) are you referring to? 2) `when I use partial classes ...`: Add your code to question. Did you make sure both partial classes are in same namespace? By default, the `Android` one will be in `namespace MyProject.Android`, but then it isn't the same class; use a cross-platform namespace such as `MyProject`. 3) You need either `partial class` or `#if SomePlatform`, to use `.PlatformView`.

Comment: *"Please dont suggest me to use Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping because this does not exist in maui class library if i want to work with nuget packages."* - Explain. Are you trying to do this in a `class library`? Please provide example code that shows exactly what you want to do (but isn't working).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Control Library and specifying handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458997/custom-control-library-and-specifying-handlers). [Granted it isn't ideal, but accepted answer there does describe the current situation, what ideally would be possible (but currently isn't), and a work-around.]

Comment: yes in the class library. that why the question. yes partial classes are in the same namespace. Handlers already works fine but they override the default values in the cross platform definition.

Comment: no it doesnt answer my question. I dont have a page, i have only controls in my class library which is used to generate nuget package.

Comment: Page is not relevant. Should be same for any UI element. BTW, I've re-arranged that answer to make it clear that currently any app that uses your library **must** put in their `MauiAppBuilder()` a call `YourLibrary.Init(builder);`, which you need to define in library. For any further help, **add code to question** showing exactly what you tried, that has the symptom you describe. Show a minimal piece of your library, and a simple usage of it in an app. Then try adapting the `Init` technique I mention, to `Append`. Or does `builder` not support `Append`? Need to see exactly what you have.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve see the updated question with the Repro. Question should be more clear now i hope.

Comment: I don't think what you want is currently possible. Create a new issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues, describing the functionality you desire. Include link to repo, and a link back to this SO question. Then add issue link to this question.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thats what i wanted to know before i make sure that i understand things correctly. this is indeed very basic usage we have been doing with Xamarin

Comment: Hopefully I’m wrong, and there is some way. This new approach seems less straightforward than Xamarin. But the new rendering approach was necessary to improve performance of complex layouts.