# How do I register a custom handler in a .NET MAUI iOS head project - not in single project - in .NET 8?

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I am trying to migrate a Xamarin.Forms application to .NET MAUI. I am trying to stick with multiple head projects as opposed to using single project.

I am trying to write a handler for a custom control for iOS. I can't register this in MauiProgram.cs because that is in the shared project and knows nothing about my iOS code.

The approach would be to register the iOS handler in AppDelegate, in the FinishedLaunching method but this code doesn't compile in .NET 8 previews (although in the past it might have worked):

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.Handlers.AddHandler<MyCustomControl, MyCustomControlHandler>();
```

What is the approach to do this in .NET 8?

Comment: "in the past it might have worked" - what does that mean? Did it or did it not work? Have you tried this with .NET 6.0 or 7.0?

Comment: I don't know if it worked before .NET 8. It doesn't work in .NET 8 now.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this is hardy "using a technology in a way that no one else is." It's just registering a handler on the iOS side of things. Usually one does this via MauiProgram.cs and use conditional compilation. That is not an option if you're not using single project, which is not a discouraged approach.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I did not learn until after my comment that Upgrade Assistant from Xamarin Forms to Maui preserves the original multiple-project layout of the XF solution. I had only seen single-project Maui solutions for the past two years. Thus, I was skeptical that the devs had test cases with the arrangement you describe. Deleting my erroneous comment. Investigating alternatives. [FYI: What you tried would never have worked; its not .Net 8 specific.]

Answer (score 0):

Currently Maui has no mechanism that would let you declare a registration method in a separate project (your app's platform-specific code), such that MauiAppBuilder would call it.

In a multi-targetted solution, one can use partial classes to bridge between xplat and platform code. This is possible because the app compiles into a single dll per platform.

I haven't figured out a way to inject the registration into Maui's DI container, in this multi-project set-up, where each platform has its own "head" project.

---

**ALTERNATIVE 1: Inject a Callback Action**

Assuming the iOS project is able to refer to classes and methods in the main project, it might be as simple as this:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static Action<MauiAppBuilder> RegisterPlatformHandlers;

    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
      var builder = ...;
      ...
      RegisterPlatformHandlers?.Invoke(builder);
      ...
      builder.Build();
    }
}
```

In ios startup:

```cs
    ...
    ....MauiProgram.RegisterPlatformHandlers = RegisterPlatformHandlers;

...
private void RegisterPlatformHandlers(MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
  builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(...), typeof(...));
  });
}
```

Note that this is similar to what currently must be done to [Register handlers in a class library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76467717/199364).

---

**ALTERNATIVE 2: DependencyService**

This is the technique used with [Xamarin Forms / use DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction):

- Define a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.dependencyservice?view=net-maui-7.0), and have each platform implement that service.

I haven't tried this, so I don't know whether that XF doc works "as is" with Maui's DependencyService. The Maui docs are all about DI Container Registration as the new approach.

Comment: If someone gets this to work, but the code is a bit different than I show, go ahead and edit with correct code. Thanks.